# What is a polyad?

Tags: terminology, category-theory

I've read the wikipedia article, but I don't speak category theory (and I'm not sure how to start so I'm just picking something that sounds interesting). So, can someone give me a simple, possibly incorrect (for learning/clarity), pragmatic (if it applies to programming, which I'm pretty sure it does) explanation of what they are and why they're cool?

I'm trying to get through some reading about the polyadic pi calculus. Perhaps that will be enlightening.

Comment: What in particular did you find confusing? Can you narrow down the question? I think it's too broad of a question as it is.